# Multiple version of dependencies in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

i'm building a java project, using gradle for version control.

I'm migrating from an old version of the Drools rules engine 5.5.0 to 6.2.0.
Instead of going 'big bang' and change everey class to use the new version, I would like to change one class at the time, and remove the old dependency when all the classes are migrated.

In my gradle.build I have set:

```
compile 'org.drools:drools-compiler:6.2.0.Final'
compile 'org.kie:kie-api:6.2.0.Final'  
compile 'org.drools:drools-core:6.2.0.Final'

compile 'org.drools:drools-core:5.5.0.Final'
compile 'org.drools:drools-compiler:5.5.0.Final'
```

But it only downloads the newest version of the libraries.
Does gradle support multiple versions of the same library?

Comment: No, because it wouldn't make sense: only one class with a given name can be used by the compiler. You can't have a project using two different classes with the same name. If the newer jar is before the older in the classpath, the compiler will check your code against the newer classes and ignore the older, and vice-versa. You should change the version, and do the migration in a separate git/svn branch.

Comment: I have a similar situation, I want to use ExoPlayer 2 for everything and ExoPlayer 1 just for FLAC, they have 2 different package names so there should be no conflict and it looks like it would make sense to have both libraries. just ignoring the ugliness of all this though

Comment: So its a compiler / class path limitation, but if we could pretend that the compiler supported disambiguation of multiple versions, e.g. we have `MyClass` that is from `com.mypkg` library and our project imports this library twice, for two different reasons, version 1 and 2. What if the compiler could rename under the hood? com.mypkg.MyClassVersion1 and com.mypkg.MyClassVersion2 ? that could work in theory? but would change how java works fundamentally. then I guess you would need to explicitly reference `MyClassVersion1` in the code, which is weird

Answer (score 22):

#### To download multiple version of the same library：

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
  configurations {
  compile5
  compile6
}
  dependencies {
  compile5 'org.osgi:org.osgi.core:5.0.0'
  compile6 'org.osgi:org.osgi.core:6.0.0'
}
  task libs(type: Sync) {
  from configurations.compile5
  from configurations.compile6
  into "$buildDir/libs"
}
```

refer to: [How to get multiple versions of the same library](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-get-multiple-versions-of-the-same-library/7400)

#### By the way

- above download two versions, while compiling with only one version

> Gradle offers the following conflict resolution strategies:
>
> **Newest**: The newest version of the dependency is used.
> This is Gradle's default strategy, and is often an appropriate choice
> as long as versions are backwards-compatible.
>
> **Fail**: A version conflict results in a build failure.
> This strategy requires all version conflicts to be
> resolved explicitly in the build script. See [ResolutionStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) for
> details on how to explicitly choose a particular version.

refer to: [23.2.3. Resolve version conflicts of Chapter 23](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)

Answer (score 8):

No gradle doesn't support multiple version of the same library. It will choose the newest by default but you can change this using

```
org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.failOnVersionConflict()
```

> In case of conflict, Gradle by default uses the newest of conflicting
>   versions. However, you can change this behavior. Use this method to
>   configure the resolution to fail eagerly on any version conflict, e.g.
>   multiple different versions of the same dependency (group and name are
>   equal) in the same Configuration.

Taken from here https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html

Comment: Is there a way to fail only on specific dependency version conflict?