# How to add two version of same dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, protocol-buffers

How can I compile the following versions in one android app?

```
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0-beta-1'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.0.0-beta-1'
```

Comment: why do you want to do that? The newer version also includes the previous version code I guess

Comment: No. When I use newer version gives me errors in pub-sub builder.
com.google.protobuf.Timestamp this section

Comment: I think it is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36722549/1346212

Comment: @kodlan I tried it. but nothing works

Comment: so I wouldn't suggest using duplicate dependencies, either open an issue on the repo or fork the repo and fix the issue yourself. In this case you still have to maintain 2 dependencies and see the changes in the code!!!