# Multiple Gradle dependency versions at the same time

Tags: java, gradle, bukkit

There are tons of threads about this all over StackOverflow, but I can't seem to find a single on about how to get them to work at the same time.

Spigot (which wraps CraftBukkit) is a very popular Minecraft server framework that adds a degree of separation from the obfuscated Minecraft code and an independent developer's code. One of the caveats is that not everything that is possible on a Minecraft server is possible through the API.

A project I'm working on requires me to be able to access some of the version-specific packages that are named along the lines of `org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.*`. Because the project I'm working on has to work across multiple versions, I need my one compiled artifact to be compatible many different versions.

How do I get Gradle to be happy with this setup? So far I have the following based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374885/multiple-version-of-dependencies-in-gradle) link:

```
configurations {
    implementation13_0
    implementation13_1
    implementation13_2
    implementation14_0
    implementation14_1
    implementation14_2
    implementation14_3
    implementation14_4
}

dependencies {
    implementation13_0 group: 'org.spigotmc', name: 'spigot', version: '1.13-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation13_1 group: 'org.spigotmc', name: 'spigot', version: '1.13.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation13_2 group: 'org.spigotmc', name: 'spigot', version: '1.13.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation14_0 group: 'org.spigotmc', name: 'spigot', version: '1.14-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation14_1 group: 'org.spigotmc', name: 'spigot', version: '1.14.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation14_2 group: 'org.spigotmc', name: 'spigot', version: '1.14.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation14_3 group: 'org.spigotmc', name: 'spigot', version: '1.14.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation14_4 group: 'org.spigotmc', name: 'spigot', version: '1.14.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

task libs(type: Sync) {
    from configurations.implementation13_0
    from configurations.implementation13_1
    from configurations.implementation13_2
    from configurations.implementation14_0
    from configurations.implementation14_1
    from configurations.implementation14_2
    from configurations.implementation14_3
    from configurations.implementation14_4
    into "$buildDir/libs"
}
```

However, when I try to build my project after running the above tasks, it doesn't recognize ANY of the versions. Does anyone have any advice on how I might get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the versions of spigot using buildtools, after that, you need to add mavenLocal() to your repositories.

Comment: That doesn't actually allow you to use all of them at the same time though. Gradle does not support that from what I've found.