# Dependency hell with gradle project

Tags: gradle, compilation

my project file contain:

```
  dependencies {
    compile("com.external.library:a:0.0.1")

    testCompile ('org.a:b:3.2.1')
}
```

this com.external.library contain dependency to package 'org.a:b:1.0.0'
whereas for unit tests and only for that I need to use org.a:b:3.2.1 version due to it has 
classes useful for unit tests but not used in production.

During compile time dependencies are change like below

```
+--- com.external.library:a:0.0.1
|    |    |    |    +--- org.a:b:1.0.0 -> 3.2.1
```

My idea was to change package name under testCompile clause so gradle will not see it in future and do not touch.

I want com.external.library to use package 'org.a:b:1.0.0' and be able to access
classes from org.a:b:3.2.1 during unit tests.

EDIT: Both version 'org.a:b:1.0.0' & 'org.a:b:3.2.1' are used during unittests
so currently I am trying to separate them via tags.

Any ideas how to do it clever?

Comment: Which Gradle version is this?

Comment: This is version 4.4.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple version of dependencies in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374885/multiple-version-of-dependencies-in-gradle)

Comment: A little. But both version 'org.a:b:1.0.0' & 'org.a:b:3.2.1' are used during unittests so currently I am trying to separate them via tags. I believe will be easier to kinda relocate them on dependency call level (rename package) so then no need to play with tags.

Comment: I need here shadowing of org.a:b:3.2.1 -> testing.a:b:3.2.1 so I can compile code accessing both 3.2.1 version classes and 1.0.0

Other ways won't work.