# Gradle : How to have separate version of same transitive dependencies in multiple dependencies

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

in my gradle project I am using below dependencies :

:beam -dataflow-java
:google-tink  (1.7.0 version)

below is transitive dependency grapgh :

beam -dataflow-java -> google-api-client: 2.2.0
google-tink -> google-api-client: 1.33.2 -> 2.2.0

here google-api-client 1.33.2 is not considered  because higher version 2.2.0 is already available. But I want my google-tink library to use google-client-api with version 1.33.2.

how to force to have 2 different version of same transitive dependencies ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple version of dependencies in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374885/multiple-version-of-dependencies-in-gradle)

Comment: No. It is mentioned that it only download the 2 versions but compile time uses only one . 

I fixed it by using the resolutionStratergy. I replaced all higher version of google-api-client with 1.33.2.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using the `resolutionStrategy`. I replaced all higher versions of `google-api-client` with 1.33.2, like below:

```
configuration.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
         eachDependency{
             if(requested.name="google-api-client"){
                userVersion("1.33.2")
         }
      }
    }
}
```